# How do I prevent Keyboard from adding its own height constraint when using view as inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to use a custom view as an accessory view over the keyboard, for various reasons, in this case, it is much preferred over manual keyboard aligning because of some other features.

Unfortunately, this is a dynamic view that defines its own height. The constraints all work fine outside of the context of an accessoryView without errors, and properly resizing

When added as a keyboardAccessoryView it seems to impose a height of whatever the frame is at the time and break other height constraints

It appears as:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003e682d0 '_UIKBAutolayoutHeightConstraint' Turntable.ChatInput:0x7fb629c15050.height == 0   (active)>"
```

(where `0` would correspond to whatever height had been used at initialization

It is also labeled `accessoryHeight` which should make it easy to remove, but unfortunately, before I can do this, I'm getting unsatisfiable constraints and the system is tossing my height constraints

Tried:

in the `inputAccessoryView` override, I tried to check for the constraints and remove it, but it doesn't exist at this time

setting `translatesAutoresizing...Constraints = false`

**tl;dr**

Using a view as a KeyboardAccessoryView is adding its own height constraint after the fact, can I remove this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like keyboard doesn't like `inputAccessoryView` with height constraint. However you still can have `inputAccessoryView` with dynamic height by using `frame` (it is still possible to use constraints **inside** your custom `inputAccessoryView`).

Please check this example:

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let textField: UITextField = {
        let view = UITextField()
        view.frame = .init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 40)
        view.borderStyle = .line
        return view
    }()

    private let customView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.frame.size.height = 100
        view.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight // without this line height won't change
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(textField)
        textField.inputAccessoryView = customView
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.customView.frame.size.height = 50
            self.textField.reloadInputViews()
        }
    }
}
```